# jQuery click function not working on appended button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this .append function which generates a button for every element:

```
.append('<button type="button" id="add">Hinzufügen</button>')
```

Then i have this function which should do something when I click on the button above. The function works on a button which is not "appended".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#add").on("click", function () {
      alert("Test");
    });   
});
```

Does anyone know, why this doesn't work?

Comment: First of all, IDs are not intended to be used on multiple elements, use a class for this.

Comment: Write your jquery after appending and your buttons with dynamic ids or a class instead please

Answer (score 1):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is ready. `jQuery` detects this state of readiness and allows you to use `ready()`. The code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run **once** the Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

You are probably appending the button after this code is being executed.

Another issue you should probably fix is making the id's attributes unique.

More about `ready()` [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I have my ready funtion above everything. Could that be the problem then?

Comment: No, you will have to attach the listeners to newly created Elements after you have created them, not through the ready fn

Comment: @GRIV
document readiness removes the need of ordering your js code. It might be related to the event delegation. As jquery on method attaches to the presently existing elements.
refer this - https://api.jquery.com/on/